# Operation Flashpoint / ARMA Cold War Assault key bindings

Tags: operation-flashpoint

I've purchased the original Operation Flashpoint from Good Old Games but am unable to set the keybindings for aircraft.
Joystick controls it does recognise *but* in game joystick input isn't registered. Any attempt to set mouse/keyboard input as flight controls fails - input from these devices isn't even registered in the control panel even when joystick input is disabled.

My Joystick is a MS Sidewinder 2.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by enabling compatibilty modus on win7 (found in Game Controllers settings dialog, button 'advanced')